# Winjs get request failing to return data

Tags: ajax, windows-8, winjs, windows-store

I encountered a strange problem. In my app I have the following code

```
WinJS.xhr({
                url: 'http://bdzservice.apphb.com/api/Route?fromStation=София&toStation=Варна&date=30/08/2013&startTime=00:00&endTime=24:00'

            }).then(function (success)
            {
                console.log(success);
            },
            function (error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
            );
```

The problem is I get an empty response text (with status 200). The Url I provided returns data through the browser and other rest clients, but in the app I get no data. Where might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode query string parameters via `encodeURIComponent` (browser does this for you automatically when pasting url).

Following code will do the trick:

```
function serialize (obj) {
var str = [];
for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
         str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
     }
 }

 return str.join("&");
};

var request = {
    fromStation: 'София',
    toStation: 'Варна',
    date: '30/08/2013',
    startTime: '00:00',
    endTime: '24:00'
};
WinJS.xhr({
    url: 'http://bdzservice.apphb.com/api/Route?' + serialize(request)
}).then(function(success) {
    console.log(success);
},
    function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```